# Problem with trying to code Chaikin Money Flow in MT4

Tags: trading

I followed along in the video linked below and wrote the code exactly as he did, but it came up with 8 errors and 2 warnings. Below the video link is a link to the code I wrote by following the instructions in the video.

[Chaikin Money Flow - Coding in MT4 (Youtube video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X11h02UVtos)

[CMF Oscillator Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QtEsHOWZLZBjQyOWuX4bgEHpUkX-MvC9/view)

Comment: I didn't realize the links didn't show up when I published my question. Here are the links to the video I watched and the code I wrote.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X11h02UVtos

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QtEsHOWZLZBjQyOWuX4bgEHpUkX-MvC9/view?usp=sharing